# Use Jekyll to generate 2 rendered versions of a post

Tags: ruby, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I know that this question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091036/two-versions-of-each-blog-post-in-jekyll) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759827/jekyll-generating-json-files-alongside-the-html-files). Both have been answered quite poorly, and none of them do what I wish/expect.

So, let me try this again.

**Goal:**

I have a blog powered by Jekyll. I would like to be able to load my posts via AJAX and use PushState to speed things up. I'm no Ruby developer, so I have a hard time figuring out what the (poorly written) plugins in the afore-mentioned questions do.

**Situation:**

My posts are all generated using the date in their path, with a trailing slash (meaning, it generates an `index.html` file):

- /2014/09/14/post-title/(index.html)
- /2015/01/02/other-post-title/(index.html)

I cannot change this pattern for SEO reasons; my blog has been online for some years and I would like to keep my URLs working without writing extensive redirection rules.

**Question:**

What I would like now is, for every post that is rendered as `index.html`, I have another version called `raw.html`.

Now here comes the tricky part (where the other questions/answers fail):

*I want to use a single template for rendering the post body, both for the `index.html` file and for the `raw.html` file.* The reason is I don't want any code duplication.

`raw.html` is basically the exact same as `index.html`, except `index.html` has a footer, header, etc. Currently, I'm achieving this through Liquid template inheritance, but I'm willing to change if required.

Anyone any ideas or pointers ?

Comment: Did you use `permalink` for your imported blog posts ?

Comment: Yes. But to clarify, I'm not importing anything. I already use Jekyll, I just want to take it to a new level.

Comment: I had the need to do what you describe, in my own Jekyll instance. See my answer here to see my implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36459375/858275 Instead of raw.html, I refer to the file as `_BARE.html`. It also assumes you are converting from markdown. Is this answer close to what you need?

Comment: I'll have to look at it, no time now. But yes, I guess that is what I was looking for, thanks!