# How to render all Jekyll pages with a different layout?

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I'm trying to create a Jekyll plugin, which should go through all posts and render them with a different layout. Can't figure out how to do that. That's what I have so far:

```
module Jekyll
  class MyGenerator < Generator
    priority :low
    def generate(site)
      site.posts.docs.each do |doc|
        page = Page.new(site, site.source, File.dirname(doc.relative_path), doc.basename)
        page.do_layout(
          site.site_payload,
          'post' => Layout.new(site, site.source, '_layouts/my.html')
        )
        page.write(?)
        site.pages << page
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This code doesn't work.

Comment: where is the point of failure - an error? no error?

Comment: @maxpleaner oh, there are many failures. it simply doesn't work, doesn't render, doesn't save the file. I understand that I'm doing it all wrong. need help from one of Jekyll contributors, I guess

Comment: I understand the sentiment. Personally never got far with Jekyll. Have you looked at another Jekyll plugin for some example code? Or tried forking Jekyll and editing the source code itself?

Comment: @maxpleaner that's how I got this code in the first place, by checking this plugin: https://github.com/juusaw/amp-jekyll But it doesn't work...

Comment: maybe the plugin is built with a different version of Jekyll than the one you're using. By the way you mean the amp-jekyll plugin doesnt work or your code doesnt work? Clearly you should look at a working plugin for an example.

Comment: @maxpleaner amp-jekyll doesn't work, even though it promises to work with Jekyll 3. I can't find any plugins that would do the same thing :( Do you know any?

Comment: [http://www.jekyll-plugins.com/](http://www.jekyll-plugins.com/) has a list of plugins; i'm not sure which work or not. Seems like Jekyll has an option to specify the layout in the "YAML frontmatter" i.e. `layout: my_layout`. It seems like your code is taking the right approach though - so just take a look at a different (working) plugin and start from there.

Answer (score 2):

In my code below, I'm rendering all my pages a second time with the `null` layout. The resulting files all have the suffix "_BARE"

```rb
module Jekyll
  class BareHtml < Page
    def initialize(site, base, dest_dir, src_dir, page)

      @site = site
      @base = base
      @dir = dest_dir
      @dest_dir = dest_dir
      @dest_name = page.basename
      file_name = "#{page.basename}_BARE.html"
      self.process(file_name)
      self.read_yaml(base, page.path)
      self.data['layout'] = nil               ###      <-- set the layout name here
    end
  end

  class BareHtmlGenerator < Generator
    safe true
    priority :low

    def generate(site)

      # Converter for .md > .html
      converter = site.find_converter_instance(Jekyll::Converters::Markdown)

      dest = site.dest
      src = site.source

      # Create destination path
      FileUtils.mkpath(dest) unless File.exists?(dest)

      site_pages = site.pages.dup

      site_pages.each do |page|
        bare = BareHtml.new(site, site.source, dest, src, page)
        bare.content = converter.convert(bare.content)
        bare.render(site.layouts, site.site_payload)
        bare.write(site.dest)
        site.pages << bare
      end

    end

  end

end
```

Comment: I think this is outdated. `site_pages` ends up being `nil`.