# How do I push new files to GitHub?

Tags: python, git, github, pygithub

I created a new repository on github.com and then cloned it to my local machine with

```
git clone https://github.com/usrname/mathematics.git
```

I added 3 new files under the folder `mathematics`

```
$ tree 
.
├── LICENSE
├── numerical_analysis
│   └── regression_analysis
│       ├── simple_regression_analysis.md
│       ├── simple_regression_analysis.png
│       └── simple_regression_analysis.py
```

Now, I'd like to upload 3 new files to my GitHub using Python, more specifically, [PyGithub](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub). Here is what I have tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# *-* coding: utf-8 *-*
from github import Github

def main():
    # Step 1: Create a Github instance:
    g = Github("usrname", "passwd")
    repo = g.get_user().get_repo('mathematics')

    # Step 2: Prepare files to upload to GitHub
    files = ['mathematics/numerical_analysis/regression_analysis/simple_regression_analysis.py', 'mathematics/numerical_analysis/regression_analysis/simple_regression_analysis.png']

    # Step 3: Make a commit and push
    commit_message = 'Add simple regression analysis'

    tree = repo.get_git_tree(sha)
    repo.create_git_commit(commit_message, tree, [])
    repo.push()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I don't know

- how to get the string `sha` for `repo.get_git_tree`
- how do I make a connection between step 2 and 3, i.e. pushing specific files

Personally, [PyGithub documentation](http://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction.html) is not readable. I am unable to find the right api after searching for long time.

Comment: To get the `sha` you'll need to use `hashlib`

Comment: @WayneWerner  that's definitely *not* what he should do. The `sha` is computed by `git` and you'll almost certainly get it wrong if you try to compute it yourself.

Comment: @BrianMalehorn I had a bash script that would upload my git commits via CURL and the github api, IIRC - it's not *that* bad.

Comment: You used `sha1sum` to compute the git hash? If so I'm impressed to got the format right.

Comment: Why not using a bash script? I guess you should have bash installed along git in your environment. You could then push via ssh with key authentication.

Comment: @MayeulC, I am more familar with Python. It is easier for me to select specific files to submit.

Comment: Then, how about calling `git` directly to interface with it? Or using a python interface such as [GitPython](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython#gitpython), not necessarily GitHub oriented? Its documentation is indeed... very sparse, and I would not call it usable.

Comment: @MayeulC, thx for this info. I am also considering `subprocess.Popen`. Anyway, I'll try GitPython as you mentioned. BTW, can you answer the question? The bounty is about to expiring in 2 days.

Comment: My understanding of the documentation is that you want to get the branch, from which you get the HEAD commit (from which you get the `sha` values for the commit, and the base tree). with that in hand, call `create_git_tree` passing the HEAD's tree as base, and giving it a list of `InputGitTreeElement` (setting `content`, but leaving `sha` alone) with your modifications. then call `create_git_commit` with your new tree. Finally, you'll need to get the branch ref and update it to your new commit `sha`. It's probably easier to find some library that wraps this one, than do it yourself though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a commit and push into repo with GitHub API v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801983/how-to-create-a-commit-and-push-into-repo-with-github-api-v3)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I tried to use the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) to commit multiple files. This page for the [Git Data API](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/) says that it should be "pretty simple". For the results of that investigation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39627647/3657941).

I recommend using something like [GitPython](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html):

```
from git import Repo

repo_dir = 'mathematics'
repo = Repo(repo_dir)
file_list = [
    'numerical_analysis/regression_analysis/simple_regression_analysis.py',
    'numerical_analysis/regression_analysis/simple_regression_analysis.png'
]
commit_message = 'Add simple regression analysis'
repo.index.add(file_list)
repo.index.commit(commit_message)
origin = repo.remote('origin')
origin.push()
```

**Note:** This version of the script was run in the parent directory of the repository.

Comment: You can only add files in the root or subdirs of the current working dir, not from parent directories.

Comment: Well, you can simply do ``os.chdir()`` to work on another dir or Git repo, such as when using a separate repository for backups. The above will also continue to work in the "new" git project.

Comment: which path need to add in file list? when i am giving path of image available in my local it show me error filenotfounderror winerror 2 python

Answer (score 9):

**Note:** This version of the script was called from inside the GIT repository because I removed the repository name from the file paths.

I finally figured out how to use [PyGithub](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub) to commit multiple files:

```
import base64
from github import Github
from github import InputGitTreeElement

token = '5bf1fd927dfb8679496a2e6cf00cbe50c1c87145'
g = Github(token)
repo = g.get_user().get_repo('mathematics')
file_list = [
    'numerical_analysis/regression_analysis/simple_regression_analysis.png',
    'numerical_analysis/regression_analysis/simple_regression_analysis.py'
]
commit_message = 'Add simple regression analysis'
master_ref = repo.get_git_ref('heads/master')
master_sha = master_ref.object.sha
base_tree = repo.get_git_tree(master_sha)
element_list = list()
for entry in file_list:
    with open(entry, 'rb') as input_file:
        data = input_file.read()
    if entry.endswith('.png'):
        data = base64.b64encode(data)
    element = InputGitTreeElement(entry, '100644', 'blob', data)
    element_list.append(element)
tree = repo.create_git_tree(element_list, base_tree)
parent = repo.get_git_commit(master_sha)
commit = repo.create_git_commit(commit_message, tree, [parent])
master_ref.edit(commit.sha)
""" An egregious hack to change the PNG contents after the commit """
for entry in file_list:
    with open(entry, 'rb') as input_file:
        data = input_file.read()
    if entry.endswith('.png'):
        old_file = repo.get_contents(entry)
        commit = repo.update_file('/' + entry, 'Update PNG content', data, old_file.sha)
```

If I try to add the raw data from a PNG file, the call to `create_git_tree` eventually calls `json.dumps` in [`Requester.py`](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/blob/master/github/Requester.py#L211), which causes the following exception to be raised:

> `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte`

I work around this problem by `base64` encoding the PNG data and committing that. Later, I use the `update_file` method to change the PNG data. This results in two separate commits to the repository which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 3):

I can give you some information support, but also one concrete solution.

[Here](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/blob/db44286366a09f1f65986db2a1c8b470fb417068/git/test/test_index.py) you can find examples of adding new files to your repository, and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AWsLtWuaz_o&feature=youtu.be) is a video tutorial for this.

Below you can see a list of python packages that work with GitHub found on the developer page of GitHub:

- [PyGithub](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub)
- [Pygithub3](https://github.com/copitux/python-github3)
- [libsaas](https://github.com/ducksboard/libsaas)
- [github3.py](https://github.com/sigmavirus24/github3.py)
- [sanction](https://github.com/demianbrecht/sanction)
- [agithub](https://github.com/jpaugh/agithub)
- [githubpy](https://github.com/michaelliao/githubpy)
- [octohub](https://github.com/turnkeylinux/octohub)
- [Github-Flask](http://github-flask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [torngithub](https://github.com/jkeylu/torngithub)

But also you can push your files with commands in IPython if you need:

```
In [1]: import subprocess
In [2]: print subprocess.check_output('git init', shell=True)
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/code/.git/
In [3]: print subprocess.check_output('git add .', shell=True)
In [4]: print subprocess.check_output('git commit -m "a commit"', shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using subprocess, this will do the same work-

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['git', 'add', '-A'])
subprocess.call(['git', 'commit', '-m', '{}'.format(commit_message)])
subprocess.call(['git', 'push', 'https://{}@github.com/user-name/repo.git'.format(token)])
```

Make sure to use -A or -all to track all the files in the project/even in parent directory. Using 'git add .' will track only the files inside the cwd where this code is written.

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen("git rev-parse HEAD".split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
sha = out.strip()
```

There's probably a way to do this with PyGithub, but this should work for a quick hack.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need pygithub specifically, the dulwich git-library offers [high level git commands](https://www.dulwich.io/docs/tutorial/porcelain.html). For the commands have a look at https://www.dulwich.io/apidocs/dulwich.porcelain.html

Comment: Thx for quick response. It would be very nice if you can provide a MWE.

Comment: @sparkandshine Sorry - what is a MWE? Minimal working example?

Comment: Exactly, [Minimal working example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example)

Comment: Thought i was using dulwich in an older project but actually  im using just normal git-commands via subprocess there - Sorry, no working example

Answer (score 0):

If PyGithub's documentation is not usable (and it doesn't look so), and you just want to push a commit (not doing anything fancy with issues, repo configuration, etc.), you would probably be better off directly interfacing with git, either calling the `git` executable or using a wrapper library such as [GitPython](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython#gitpython).

Using `git` directly with something such as `subprocess.Popen` that you mentioned would probably be easier on the leaning curve, but also more difficult in the long term for error handling, etc. since you don't really have nice abstractions to pass around, and would have to do the parsing yourself.

Getting rid of PyGithub also frees you from being tied to GitHub and its API, allowing you to push to any repo, even another folder on your computer.