# How to commit and push files using python library GitPython

Tags: python, github, gitpython

Requirement:

- Commit and push files to GitHub repository from a python script.
- The credentials should be included in the script.

Issue:

- If credentials are provided in the script the commit operation is
  executing and throwing the following error,

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/amith/example.py", line 14, in <module>
>     repo.index.add(folder_path)
> AttributeError: 'Repository' object has no attribute 'index'
> ```

- If credentials are, **not** provided in the script the commit operation is working properly by providing it on the terminal.

***I need to integrate this script in Django application which should accept the credentials from the configuration file.***

I have tried the following links but nothing has worked for me yet.
- [link1](https://developer.github.com/v3/)
- [link2](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pygithub/latest/pygithub.pdf)
- [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38594717/how-do-i-push-new-files-to-github)

```
from git import Repo
from github import Github
from pdb import set_trace as bp

repo_dir = '--------'
repo = Repo(repo_dir)

# using username and password

g = Github("-----", "------")
folder_path = '----------'
commit_message = 'Add New file'
repo.index.add(folder_path)
repo.index.commit(commit_message)
origin = repo.remote('origin')
origin.push()
```

So, I am getting this error "AttributeError: 'Repository' object has no attribute 'index'".

Complete error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amith/example.py", line 14, in <module>
    repo.index.add(folder_path)
AttributeError: 'Repository' object has no attribute 'index'
```

Comment: Please post the gitpython package version number, the  __exact__ error message (copy-pasted) AND the __full__ traceback (idem). Also you may want to edit your question's title to reflect your _real_ issue.

Comment: GitPython==2.1.11 - version, Complete error message I have edited

Comment: And where are the __exact__ error message and full traceback ?

Comment: So what the `repo` variable actually contains? Ideally, just before the exception is thrown, i.e. on line 14?

Comment: repo = Repository(full_name="my repo name")