# Tag not visibile when added via the Github API

Tags: github, github-api, git-tag

I am currently attempting to build a small program, that, using the Github API would make a small change to a file in a repository, add a tag to the commit that change belongs to, then points the HEAD of the branch to said commit, which would then trigger Actions, after the entire operation has completed. I noticed, however, that when I tested my code, the commit would show up, but there would not be a tag visible anywhere. I made note of the fact that the API was, in fact, receiving the request to set the tag, and there it seems to have gone through, but not on the repo itself it seems.

For reference, I was following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801983/how-to-create-a-commit-and-push-into-repo-with-github-api-v3/63461333#63461333) tutorial, and then adding [this](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/git#create-a-tag-object) call after step 4.

Any help would be very much appreciated!