# Multiple files under a single commit through GitHub API

Tags: github, github-api, github-api-v3

Each commit contains 2 files uploaded to GitHub, we have a few of such commits.
we have only one branch (Main), We need to bound these commits with a branch so that we can view all files that were pushed.
The problem comes when we attach a commit with a branch, my new commit deletes every change made by my previous commit

```
   commit 1 : assets/bg1.png
           uploads/profile1.png

   commit 2 : assets/bg2.png
           uploads/profile2.png
```

For now, if I attach commit-2 with the main branch, It deletes changes made by commit  1
I need both commit changes available in the Git branch

[Steps that I followed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63461333/7840849)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There's nowhere near enough detail here to even start looking into it.

Comment: @LayneBernardo 
Thank you for your time, I have update my question